# How to properly write "deplano"?

Tags: ortografía, coloquialismos

There's a popular (and probably exclusively) guatemalan expression: *deplano* or *de plano*; meaning *probably* or *surely*, analogue to *seguramente*.

Example (provided for completion purposes):

> -¿Dónde está Juan?
>   -Deplano se fue a comer.

Now, this might be a too colloquial or informal word to have its own official spelling, but I still wonder if there is a "proper" way to write it. My gut tells me it should be written as a single word, but it's easy to get orthography wrong.

Also, if you know of other places where it's said, please comment!

Comment: Debería ser _de plano_, una preposión y un sustantivo y entre ellos un espacio. Quizás ud. lo escucha muy rápido y por eso uno creería que debe escribirse unida la expresión.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an adverbial phrase written as two words.  It's somewhat recognized in the DRAE, via the judicial sense of *de plano* meaning "Que se adopta inmediatamente y sin trámites" (*plano. de plano. 3.*) which was likely picked up and used more colloquially, converting it from an adjective phrase to an adverbial along the way.

Comment: Gracias! Link para los demás: http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=plano

Answer (score 3):

As @David explains in his comment it is written *de plano*.It is not written as a single word.

It means *directly*, *going straight to the point*.